# When does a closed contour integral vanish?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I've had some issues with Cauchy's Thorem for a little while now. Namely, when does a closed contour integral nrcessarily equal 0.

The statement I have learned is:

If $f $ is analytic on a simply-connected domain, $E $, and $C $ is a piecewise smooth closed curve on $E $ then:
$$\oint_C f(z)dz = 0$$

My trouble comes up with the *simply-connected* criteron, so I was hoping that someone could give me an answer to this:

> If $f $ is analytic on a connected domain $E $ with a hole centered at $z_0$, and $C$ is a closed curve which contains $z_0$, but does not intersect it, can we still say that 
>   $$\oint_C f (z)dz = 0$$

Personally, I see no reason to think this is untrue. It seems to me that Cauchy's Theorem requires simply connected domains just so that you can say *every* closed curve vanishes. But I suspect that a closed contour integral should still equal $0$ if the integrand is analytic and the curve stays completely within the domain. Is this true, or am I looking at things incorrectly?

Comment: Is $\{z:z\ne0\}$ a connected domain with a hole centred at $0$ and is the unit circle a closed curve that contains $0$ but does not intersect it?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Yes, that would be an example of what I am talking about. Would the integral of any analytic function along the unit circle be $0$ in such a domain?

Comment: Short answer:no! I don't have time to write a longer answer, but look at residues.

Comment: @Henrik: Thanks, I'll look into that (I haven't learned about residues as of yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at things incorrectly. The integral 
$$\int_{\{z:|z|=1\}}\frac{1}{z}$$ does not vanish

(Aassume $f(z) =\frac{1}{z}$ to be defined on $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$).

Comment: Assuming you're taking the domain to be something which does not contain $0$ here, I think that cleared things up a bit now. So in reality, we could take a function that was analytic at all points on the interior of the closed curve, and *this* closed contour integral would vanish, even if the domain wasn't simply connected, because we could *extend* the domain to be something which was simply connected (with $f $ analytic on it). Is that correct?

Comment: For example, integrating $f (z) = z $ on the same closed curve in your example would be $0$, even if the domain we were integrating on didn't necessarily contain all points inside the curve (i.e. wasn't simply connected)

Comment: I'm not sure I got your statement correctly, but in fact, if $f$ is defined e.g. on the unit disc without a point and can be analytically continued to the domain including the point, then the integral along any closed curve would vanish. This is because you cannot distinguish between $f$ and its continuation along the curve, and the statement is true for the continuation.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant! Thank you for clearing that up for me!